# How to solve $x'(t) =\frac {10 - x(t)}{2000}$, such that $x(0) = 0$, without using complex numbers

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Wolfram Alpha shows this intermediary step:

Solve the equation:
$$c = 2000\, i π + 2000 \log(10)$$

It is however for a class where students have not yet learned complex numbers. How can they solve this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you. Editing..

Comment: So you are just trying to solve $$y’=ay+b, y(0)=0$$ with given constants $a,b$? Can’t you just use a power series method?

Comment: This is freshman calculus. They have not done that either.

Answer (score 2):

This equation is separable
$$\displaystyle \frac {dx}{dt} = -\frac {(x - 10)}{2000},  x(0) = 0$$
$$\int \frac {dx}{x-10}=-\frac 1 {2000}\int dt$$
$$\ln(x-10)=-\frac t {2000}+K$$
for $x<10$
$$ \displaystyle 10-x=Ke^{-\frac t {2000}}$$
$$ \displaystyle x=10+Ce^{-\frac t {2000}}$$
The constant for the initial condition given is
$$x(0)=0 \implies C=-10$$
$$ \implies \displaystyle x(t)=10(1-e^{-\frac t {2000}})$$

Answer (score 0):

This is just a first order differential equation. Try separation of variable or use integrating factor.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{x}{2000}=\frac1{200}$$

Multiply by $\exp\left(\frac{t}{2000} \right)$,

$$\exp\left(\frac{t}{2000} \right)\frac{dx}{dt}+\exp\left(\frac{t}{2000} \right)\frac{x}{2000}=\frac1{200}\exp\left(\frac{t}{2000} \right)$$

it can be simplified to

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(x \exp\left(\frac{t}{2000}\right)\right)=\frac1{200}\exp\left(\frac{t}{2000} \right)$$

Integrate both sides by $t$ and hopefully you can complete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Considering
$$x' =\frac {10 - x}{2000}\implies x'+\frac { x}{2000}=\frac 1{200}$$
the homogeneous equation is simple
$$x=c \,e^{-t/2000}$$ Using Now the veriation of parameters, the full equation becomes
$$c' \,e^{-t/2000}=\frac{1}{200}\implies c'=\frac{e^{t/2000} }{200}\implies c=10 e^{t/2000}+K$$ Back to $x$
$$x=K e^{-t/2000}+10$$ So, if $x(0)=0$, then $K=-10$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=10-x$.
The equation becomes
$-y'=ya$
wifh $a=1/2000$ and
$y(0)=10$.

This is
$y'/y=-a$
so
$\ln y=-at+c$
or
$y=Ce^{-at}$
or
$x=10-Ce^{-at}$.

Set $t=0$ to find
$C=10$.